# Is there hidden storage in android devices

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage

Is there any Hidden Storage in android devices . my android phone has 4GB ROM (Internal Storage) 1.5GB usable . I have scanned the phone with recovery software to recover deleted files i have found 11GB of deleted files for recovering. how is it possible it has only 4GB available does it has some hidden storage

I am not asking about the link reference of files or overwritten of deleted file .i am  asking about my rom is 4GB and deleted files are 11GB( showed in the recovery software ) it should be 4GB thats the maximum space available in the phone .  but there is extra 7 GB where are these files located in the device .

Answer (score 0):

You're not approaching that quite right. Every time you boot your phone, start and app, flush your cache and so on you are rewriting real files time and again.
PNG, TXT, XML, most commonly, and so on. Those overwritten and/or deleted files don't ever actually "disappear" from your device. Their link/reference is removed from your device's file allocation tables [more a windows descript on that, but still prety much the same] but, the remnants do just that. They remain. Your recovery tool keys in on file magic and/or footers , usually contained in a definition file and copies over the recovered files to a specified location. May of those files are duplicates of the basic png files that make up your apk UI's as well as the os. Most of those recovered files will be broken though.

The only sure fire way to actually delete a file is a secure wipe, and there are different standards of secure on that point.